# find first element in array for which block returns true and return the block's return value

Tags: ruby

I need to iterate over an array and apply a supplied block to each element, and return the first true value returned by the block, which implies that I need to stop immediately as soon as I get a true value.

below is my code. I am a ruby newbie, and I am not sure if this code is reinventing the wheel. Maybe there is a library method or methods that can do that already? or may be this code can be simplified?

```
RS = {
  :x => %w(\d+ a\d+ bb\d+ ccc\d+).map{|x| /^#{x}$/},
  :y => %w(\w+ 1\w+ 22\w+ 333\w+).map{|x| /^#{x}$/}
}.freeze

def find s, t
  r = RS[s]
  if r
    r.each do |p|
      m = p.match t
      return m if m
    end
    nil
  end
end

p find :x, 'bb12345'
```

Comment: You're looking for something like [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) that returns what the block returned rather than which element caused the block to return the truthy value?

Comment: I think what you're doing is about all there is. You could pretty it up a bit and monkey patch it into Enumerable but that's about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functionally find mapping of first value that passes a test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604636/functionally-find-mapping-of-first-value-that-passes-a-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully still actual: here a solution using detect, i made it possible to verbose the output so you can see which expressions are evaluated before returning a hit.

```
def find_match symbol, string , verbose = false, match = nil
  if verbose
    RS.detect{|x,v|x==symbol;v.detect{|re|puts re;match=string.match(/#{re}/)}}
  else
    RS.detect{|x,v|x==symbol;v.detect{|re|match=string.match(/#{re}/)}}
  end
  match
end

p find_match :x, 'bb12345'
p find_match :x, 'ee12345' , true #verbose output
p find_match :x, '12345'
p find_match :y, '22abcd'

#<MatchData "bb12345">
(?-mix:^\d+$)
(?-mix:^a\d+$)
(?-mix:^bb\d+$)
(?-mix:^ccc\d+$)
(?-mix:^\w+$)
#<MatchData "ee12345">
#<MatchData "12345">
#<MatchData "22abcd">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result of the block you could do it this way. This will iterate over the whole array, but wont evaluate any matches after the first one.

```
def find(s,t)
  RS[s].inject(nil) {|m, p| m || p.match(t)}
end
```

You can break out early doing something like this

```
RS[s].inject(nil) {|m, p| (m && (break m)) || p.match(t)}
```

Comment: thanks. I need to return `true` in this case because this is the value  that the block returns.

Answer (score 2):

This is duplicated with: [Ruby - Array.find, but return the value the block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900696/ruby-array-find-but-return-the-value-the-block/46789688#46789688)

You want a lazy map:

```
[nil, 1, 2, 3].lazy.map{|i| i && i.to_s}.find{|i| i}    
# => "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your regex patterns are simple, you can just apply the regex again at the end, maybe.

Something like:

```
def find(s,t)
  r = RS[s] and r.find{|p| p.match(t)}.try(:match, t)
end
```

Although it makes one redundant call to match, it is easier to understand.

First, find the pattern you want, then use that pattern.