# Functionally find mapping of first value that passes a test

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

In Ruby, I have an array of simple values (possible encodings):

```
encodings = %w[ utf-8 iso-8859-1 macroman ]
```

I want to keep reading a file from disk until the results are valid. I could do this:

```
good = encodings.find{ |enc| IO.read(file, "r:#{enc}").valid_encoding? }
contents = IO.read(file, "r:#{good}")
```

...but of course this is dumb, since it reads the file twice for the good encoding. I could program it in gross procedural style like so:

```
contents = nil
encodings.each do |enc|
  if (s=IO.read(file, "r:#{enc}")).valid_encoding?
    contents = s
    break
  end
end
```

But I want a functional solution. I could do it functionally like so:

```
contents = encodings.map{|e| IO.read(f, "r:#{e}")}.find{|s| s.valid_encoding? }
```

…but of course that keeps reading files for every encoding, even if the first was valid.

Is there a simple pattern that is functional, but does not keep reading the file after a the first success is found?

Comment: Do you mean `find`? `first` doesn't take a block.

Comment: @sepp2k Bah, of course I did. Thanks. I've edited to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you sprinkle a `lazy` in there, `map` will only consume those elements of the array that are used by `find` - i.e. once `find` stops, `map` stops as well. So this will do what you want:

```
possible_reads = encodings.lazy.map {|e| IO.read(f, "r:#{e}")}
contents = possible_reads.find {|s| s.valid_encoding? }
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'lazy' for #<Array:0x2b08c00>`

Comment: @Phrogz It's new in 2.0. In earlier versions you could use the `backports` gem or just stick with the code you have (or upgrade if that's an option).

Comment: Ahh; I thought I saw it in the 1.9.3 docs. Your answer is elegant, but I'm going to leave this open for a day in case there's another solution other than `lazy`.

Comment: Piggybacked a complimentary answer to help if you're stuck on 1.9 for some reason.  Please accept sepp2k's answer if you use this approach, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Hopping on sepp2k's answer:  If you can't use 2.0, lazy enums can be easily implemented in 1.9:

```
class Enumerator

  def lazy_find
    self.class.new do |yielder|
      self.each do |element|
        if yield(element)
          yielder.yield(element)
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

a = (1..100).to_enum
p a.lazy_find { |i| i.even? }.first

# => 2
```

Comment: The method should be called `lazy_select` because it does what `select` does (but lazily). However doing `lazy_select {...}.first` just does the same thing that `find` already does. For what Phrogz wants, you'd need `lazy_map`, not `lazy_select`.

Comment: It's just an example, it's easy to extrapolate this to any lazy flavored enumerator.  Also, #select returns multiple matches; #find returns the first match only.  The #first call at the end of the enumerable chain is just to get that value out of the enumerable.

Comment: For that matter, no need to use `Enumerator`: `module Enumerable; def find_mapped; each{|o| if v=yield(o) then return v end }; end; end` and then `contents = encodings.find_mapped{|enc| (s=IO.read(f,"r:#{enc}")).valid_encoding? && s }`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36159535/1115652) statement:

```
contents = encodings.each do |e|

    s = IO.read( f, "r:#{e}" )
    s.valid_encoding? and break s

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is with our good friend `inject`:

```
contents = encodings.inject(nil) do |s,enc|
  s || (c=File.open(f,"r:#{enc}").valid_encoding? && c
end
```

This is still sub-optimal because it continues to loop through encodings after finding a match, though it doesn't do anything with them, so it's a minor ugliness. Most of the ugliness comes from...well, the code itself. :/