# Using `inject`, `unless`, and `next` to determine the minimum value

Tags: ruby, iteration, inject

I have this code:

```
def test(vertices, distances)
  until vertices.empty?
    nearest_vertex = vertices.inject do |a, b|
      p "a = #{a}: b = #{b}"
      p "distances[a] = #{distances[a]}, distances[b] = #{distances[b]}"
      next b unless distances[a] #next b if distances[a] == true
      next a unless distances[b] #next a if distances[b] == true
      next a if distances[a] < distances[b]
      p "b = #{b}"
      b
    end
    p "nearest_vertex = #{nearest_vertex}"
    vertices.delete nearest_vertex
  end
end

vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
distances = {1 => 0, 2 => 3, 3 => 2, 4 => 18, 5 => nil, 6 => 7}
test(vertices, distances)
```

Which outputs:

```
"a = 1: b = 2"
"distances[a] = 0, distances[b] = 3"
"a = 1: b = 3"
"distances[a] = 0, distances[b] = 2"
...
"a = 1: b = 6"
"distances[a] = 0, distances[b] = 7"
"nearest_vertex = 1"
```

Here, `b = 6` isn't printed. Is this because `next` issues a stop iteration command?

```
"a = 2: b = 3"
"distances[a] = 3, distances[b] = 2"
"b = 3"
```

Why doesn't the iteration continue to `a=2: b=4` here?

```
"a = 3: b = 4"
"distances[a] = 2, distances[b] = 18"
"a = 3: b = 5"
"distances[a] = 2, distances[b] = "
"a = 3: b = 6"
"distances[a] = 2, distances[b] = 7"
"nearest_vertex = 3"
...
```

Once `a` is set to `3`, everything works as I thought it should. How does the program know that `nearest_vertex` is three?

I don't understand the interaction between `inject` and `next` in determining how and when to declare a vertex to be the `nearest_vertex`. How are the distances compared when there is no comparison operator?

Comment: I believe you mixed the accumulator and element in block to `inject` up. According to your comments, you expect it to be `|element, accum|` whilst it is exactly the opposite: `|accum, element|`. Try to swap `|a, b|` to `|b, a|`.

Comment: "nearest" to what?

Comment: Thanks to the Tin Man for editing my original post. This is my first question posted on StackOverflow and the original format was less than optimal. Nearest is simply comparing "a" to all of the other "b"s and selecting the lowest number. It's a small piece of code taken out of context from an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Let me explain `Enumerable#inject` in pure Ruby. Note that the following code is **NOT** the original implementation of `Enumerable#inject`. For clarity, I will explain it in class `Array`, and focus on the most basic usage `ary.inject(&block)`:

```
class Array
  def inject(&block)
    return nil if self.empty?

    enumerator = self.each

    accumulator = enumerator.next

    loop do
      begin
        accumulator = block.call(accumulator, enumerator.next)
      rescue StopIteration
        break
      end
    end

    accumulator
  end
end
```

You can see that in the loop, the accumulator of previous iteration and the current element of the array is passed to the block's params, and the block's return value is reassigned to the accumulator.

Then what is `next x` in a block?

You can think of a block as an anonymous function, and the keyword `next` is its `return`. It terminates the current block call and makes the block return `x` (`nil` if the return value is not explicitly specified).

By the way, `break x` in a block terminates the method call which takes the block, and makes the method return `x`. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].inject do |acc, n|
   break n if n == 2
   acc + n
end
=> 2
```

The `Array#inject` is terminated by the `break` when `n` is `2`, and that `n` is returned.

`return` in a block terminates the method call which calls the method that takes the block. For example:

```
def foo
  [1, 2, 3].inject do |acc, n|
    return n
  end
  puts 'You will never see this this sentence.'
end

foo
=> 2
```

And there is no sentence printed, because `foo` is terminated by `return`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me better understand the inject method. Using it in combination with unless was really confusing but I think I understand it much better now.

Answer (score 3):

### How `inject` works

The block passed to `inject` receives two arguments in each iteration. The first argument (`prev_nearest_key` here) is an "accumulator" whose value is whatever value was returned by the previous iteration. (For the first iteration it will be the argument given to `inject` or, inits absence, the first element of the collection—`vertices[0]` here.) The second argument (`key`) is the current element of the collection. When iteration is complete, the final value of the accumulator is returned.

When you call `next val` in a block passed to an iterator, `val` is immediately returned from the block and the next iteration begins. To demonstrate, here's how it looks with `map`:

```
["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"].map do |letter|
  next letter.upcase if "aeoiu".include?(letter)
  letter
end
# => ["h", "E", "l", "l", "O"]
```

Above, when `letter` is a vowel, `letter.upcase` is returned from the block and the next line is never evaluated. When `letter` isn't a vowel, it's returned from the block unchanged.

Here's a similar example with inject:

```
["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"].inject do |accum, letter|
  next accum + letter.upcase if "aeoiu".include?(letter)
  accum + letter
end
# => "hEllO"
```

What's different here? When `letter` is a vowel, `accum + letter.upcase` is returned from the block (effectively appending `letter.upcase` to `accum`), and the next line is never evaluated. When `letter` isn't a vowel, `accum + letter` is returned from the block. In both cases, the value returned from the block becomes `accum` in the next iteration.

### How your code works

Here's your code, but with more intelligible variable names.

```
nearest_vertex = vertices.inject do |prev_nearest_vertex, current_vertex|
  next current_vertex unless distances[prev_nearest_vertex]
  next prev_nearest_vertex unless distances[current_vertex]
  next prev_nearest_vertex if distances[prev_nearest_vertex] < distances[current_vertex]
  current_vertex
end
```

I've renamed `a`, the accumulator, to `prev_nearest_vertex`, since it's the value returned by the previous iteration, and `b` to `current_vertex`.

The first two lines inside the block are just checking to see if `distances[prev_nearest_vertex]` and `distances[current_vertex]` are `nil`. They could (and, perhaps, should) be written like this instead:

```
next current_vertex if distances[prev_nearest_vertex].nil?
next prev_nearest_vertex if distances[current_vertex].nil?
```

The first line basically says, "If the previous nearest vertex's distance is `nil`, then it's not the nearest, so set `prev_nearest_vertex` to `current_vertex` in the next iteration." The second line says "If the current vertex's distance is `nil`, then it's not the nearest, so keep `prev_nearest_vertex` the same in the next iteration.

And here are the third and fourth lines:

```
next prev_nearest_vertex if distances[prev_nearest_vertex] < distances[current_vertex]
current_vertex
```

These could be rewritten like this:

```
if distances[prev_nearest_vertex] < distances[current_vertex]
  prev_nearest_vertex
else
  current_vertex
end
```

It just says, "Set `prev_nearest_vertex` in the next iteration to `prev_nearest_vertex` if its distance is less; otherwise set it to `current_vertex`.

This is pretty good code, but you should probably...

### Do this instead

Ruby's Enumerable module has a lot of really useful methods, including one called [`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by). It evaluates the given block for each element in an Enumerable and returns the element for which the lowest value was returned. To demonstrate, consider this `map`:

```
words = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
words.map {|word| word.size }
# => [5, 5, 5, 3, 4]
```

This just turns an array of words into an array of their sizes. Now suppose we want to get the word that's the shortest. This is easy with `min_by`:

```
words = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
words.min_by {|word| word.size }
# => "sit"
```

Instead of returning the words' sizes, this calculates their sizes and then returns the word whose size is the smallest.

This is directly applicable to your code. Again, consider a `map` operation:

```
vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
distances = { 1 => 0, 2 => 3, 3 => 2, 4 => 18, 5 => nil, 6 => 7 }

vertices.map do |vertex|
  distances[vertex] || Float::INFINITY
end
# => [0, 3, 2, 18, Infinity, 7]
```

This produces an array of distances corresponding to the elements in `vertices`, but `nil` distances are replaced with `Float::INFINITY`. This is useful because `n < Float::INFINITY` is true for every number `n`. As before, we can now replace `map` with `min_by` to get the vertex corresponding to the smallest distance:

```
def test(vertices, distances)
  vertices.min_by {|vertex| distances[vertex] || Float::INFINITY }
end

test(vertices, distances)
# => 1
```